# C# Object reference null but not null

Tags: c#, class, object, reference, null

The forum is full of posts about problems like this. I've red some but didn't manage to solve my own problem.
I get Exception error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
        try
        {
            CZaposleni zap = new CZaposleni();
            zap.Sifra = "1234567894567";
            zap.Ime = "testIme";
            zap.Prezime = "testPrezime";
            zap.Pol = Char.Parse("M");
            zap.JMBG = "1234567899871";
            zap.Brknjizice = "12345";
            zap.SS = "4.test";
            zap.DatumR = DateTime.Parse("4/11/2013");
            zap.DatumZ = DateTime.Parse("4/11/2013");
            zap.Mestorodj = "testMesto";
            zap.Prebivaliste = "testPrebivaliste";
            zap.Kontakt1 = "654987";
            zap.Kontakt2 = "564845";
            CRadnaMesta rad = new CRadnaMesta();
            rad.ID = Int32.Parse(cbRadnaMesta.SelectedValue.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Zap = "+zap.ID +" Rad = "+rad.ID);
            zap.Radnomesto = rad;
            Console.WriteLine("Zap check 1: " + zap.ID + " " + zap.Radnomesto.ID);
            zap.dodajRadnika();
            Console.WriteLine("Zap check 2: "+zap.ID+" "+zap.Radnomesto.ID);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Frm: "+ex.Message);
        }
```

The code breaks at 'zap.Radnomesto = rm;' since last output when running the code i get is

> rm.ID = 1
>   zap.ID = 0

So none of two objects is null.

Comment: When asking about an error, **always** include the full stack trace of the error. If this code is really throwing that error on the line you say, then `Radnomesto` is a *property* and the error is being thrown within its setter.

Comment: Please post the minimal code necessary to reproduce this.

Comment: I suspect `Radnomesto` could be a property with a `set` accessor in which the problem arises.

Comment: Inside CZaposleni:
        public CRadnaMesta Radnomesto
        {
            get { return radnomesto; }
            set
            {
                if (radnomesto.ID == 0)
                   throw new Exception("Morate uneti radno mesto.");
                radnomesto = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Please post whatever parts of the code you need. I don't want to make a mess :D

Comment: Inside that setter is the radnomesto value null?

Comment: Debug `CZaposleni.Radnomesto` property.

Comment: Yeah, it says CZaposleni.Radnomesto is null. But how and why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error is in the `CZaposleni` class in the following code:

```
public CRadnaMesta Radnomesto
{
    get
    {
        return radnomesto;
    }
    set
    {
        if ( radnomesto.ID == 0 )
            throw new Exception("Morate uneti radno mesto.");
        radnomesto = value;
    }
}
```

More precisely in `if ( radnomesto.ID == 0 )`. Since `radnomesto` is null if not set, you're getting the error while checking for the ID.

You should use the following code instead:

```
public CRadnaMesta Radnomesto
{
    get
    {
        return radnomesto;
    }
    set
    {
        if ( value == null || value.ID == 0 )
            throw new Exception("Morate uneti radno mesto.");
        radnomesto = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it breaks at throw Exception every time..

Comment: In the comments above, the OP said the setter looked like this: `public CRadnaMesta Radnomesto { set { if (radnomesto.ID == 0) throw new Exception("Morate uneti radno mesto."); radnomesto = value; } }` If that code is breaking with a null object then it most likely means the radnomesto is null and your code changes are not going to fix that exception if that is the case.

Comment: But radnomesto class (adding/changing/removing/listing) works perfectly...:/

Comment: @Morsus You don't you have a setter on CRadnaMesta.ID too by any chance, do you? Because that could be causing the ID to be 0...

Comment: @GGG  public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
Same goes for CZaposleni class ID

Comment: @Morsus From the error that you're reporting, the value of `cbRadnaMesta.SelectedValue.ToString()` is `"0"` causing `rad.ID` to be 0, since `Int32.Parse` throws an Exception on an invalid number format, so I think that could be the problem.

Comment: @GGG Tried with rad.ID = 1; same error.

Comment: @Morsus sorry, it was an error in my code, `value != null` should be `value == null`

Comment: @GGG Same error inside class. :/

Comment: @Morsus Same error as in the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` or `Morate uneti radno mesto.`?

Comment: @GGG Object reference,but this time from inside class. Not from form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112570/discussion-between-morsus-and-ggg).